# self organisation map : visualisation with color

Tags: python, matplotlib

i try to develope a self organisation map but i have a basical problem, i don't find a solution to write the color in pcolor
my script :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv("/Users/alainmeo/Desktop/deep learning auto 
adaptating map/data.csv",
                  header=None, sep=';')
x = dataset.iloc[:].values


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler()

x = sc.fit_transform(x)

from minisom import MiniSom

som = MiniSom(x=10, y=10, input_len=5)

som.train_random(x, num_iteration=100)


from pylab import bone, pcolor, colorbar, plot, show
bone()

for i, x in enumerate(x):
 liste = list(x)
 liste[0]=liste[0]*255
 liste[1]=liste[1]*255
 liste[2]=liste[2]*255
 liste[3]=liste[3]*255
 print(liste)
 w = som.winner(x)
 if liste[0]>liste[1] and liste[0]>liste[2] and liste[0]>liste[3]: 
      pcolor(w[0]+0.5 ,w[1]+0.5, cmap="RdBu")

 if liste[1]>liste[0] and liste[1]>liste[2] and liste[1]>liste[3]:
     pcolor(w[0]+0.5 ,w[1]+0.5, cmap="RdBu")

 if liste[2]>liste[1] and liste[2]>liste[0] and liste[2]>liste[3]: 
     pcolor(w[0]+0.5 ,w[1]+0.5, cmap="RdBu")

 if liste[3]>liste[1] and liste[3]>liste[2] and liste[3]>liste[0]: 
     pcolor(w[0]+0.5 ,w[1]+0.5, cmap="RdBu")
show()
```

my error

```
line 5553, in _pcolorargs
    'Illegal arguments to %s; see help(%s)' % (funcname, funcname))

TypeError: Illegal arguments to pcolor; see help(pcolor)
```

i want to have for each value of an output neuron a one color intensity on the map, but i don't find the solution. Can you help me?

thank you in advance

Comment: `pcolor` does not add single pixels on a map. Instead it expects an array (together with positions)  to plot. Try to separate data creation from plotting. Create one single array with what you want to show, then supply that single array (together with the respective coordinate arrays) to `pcolor`.

Comment: thx very mutch :)) probleme over ;)